# Что такое инвариант в ООП?

Tags: c#, архитектура, терминология

Очень часто в статьях по ООП  встречается такое слово, как инвариант:

- ...не позволяет модели обеспечивать собственные инварианты
- убедиться в выполнении предусловия можно исходя из постусловий и инвариантов предшествующих вызовов
- Это кстати называется принципом инварианта. собственно инкапсуляция и позволяет сохранять инвариант.
- То есть независимо от одновременного количества потребителей, она будет сохранять свои инварианты и придерживаться контракта.
- У каждого агрегата есть корень (Aggregate Root) и граница, внутри которой всегда должны быть удовлетворены инварианты.

Что имеется ввиду под этим термином? Как выглядят инварианты в коде?

Я нашёл описание термина "[инвариант цикла](https://habr.com/post/91698/)":

> Инвариант цикла – это соотношение, которое истинно перед циклом,
>   истинно в процессе выполнения цикла и истинно при выходе из цикла. Все
>   это описано у Дейкстры в книге «Дисциплина программирования», и
>   детально разжевано у Гриса в книге «Наука программирования».

А хотелось бы понять, что понимают под инвариантом

1. в программировании по контракту и
2. чистом ООП (я так понял, это имеет отношение к инкапсуляции)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Инвариант в математике - это выражение которое сохраняет свое значение. В программировании инвариантом также называют предикат который всегда истинный.

Таким образом, инвариант объекта в ООП - это либо (чаще) условие которое остается истинным после вызова любых методов объекта в любой последовательности, либо (реже) выражение которое сохраняет свое значение после вызова любых методов.

В коде инварианты чаще всего никак не выражены, но иногда ставятся защитные проверки которые их проверяют.

---

Примеры инвариантов.

[`List<>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs): 0 ≤ _size ≤ _items.Length

[`List<>.Enumerator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140): list.version = const = version; есть защитная проверка

[`List<>.Enumerator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140): 0 ≤ index ≤ list._size+1

[`ArraySegment<>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/arraysegment.cs): Array = null && Offset = 0 && Count = 0 || Array != null && 0 ≤ Offset && 0 ≤ Count && Offset + Count ≤ Array.Length; этот инвариант представлен в коде в виде конструкции Contract.Assert

Answer (score 8):

Инварианты в коде обычно выглядят:

1. Как транзакции - какие то изменения, которые либо прошли целиком, либо целиком откатились.
2. Как валидации перед сохранением - которые либо дали сохранить изменения, либо упали с ошибкой о некорректном состоянии.
3. В целом, любое исключение может оказаться следствием поддержки инварианта - обеспечение целостности, частный случай - ObjectDisposedException.
4. Функциональные программы часто инвариантны, т.к. не меняют состояние исходного объекта.
5. Приватные поля объекта, которые может менять только сам объект, плюс каждый публичный метод меняет их из рабочего и согласованного состояния в рабочее и согласованное состояние.

Answer (score 7):

Инвариант в объектно-ориентированном программировании — выражение, определяющее непротиворечивое внутреннее состояние объекта. ([Википедия: Инвариант](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82))

Comment: Как-то мало, чесслово. Примеры, как это выглядит в коде? Для чего нужно?

Comment: @AK примеры чего? Класса с непротиворечивым состоянием?

Comment: Я имел ввиду примеры выражений, но видимо (судя по последнему комментарию) тогда ещё и примеры классов с не/противоречивым состоянием. Ваш ответ не сильно прибавляет мне понимания, где, для чего и как использовать инварианты.

Comment: @AK из нельзя использовать. "объект сохранятет инвариант" означает "внутреннее состояние объекта остается непротиворечивым"

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
 
class Minute{
     
    private $seconds;
    
    public function __construct(int $value){
         if(!$this->invariant($value)){
             throw new Exception("Нарушен инвариант. 
             Значение должно быть не меньше 1 и не больше 59");
         }
         // Гарантия учтенных инвариантов !
         $this->seconds = $value;
    }
    
    public function invariant(int $value):bool{
         if ( 1 <= $value && $value <=59 ){
            return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
    
    public function addSecond(){
         if(!$this->invariant( $this->seconds+1)){
             throw new Exception("Нарушен инвариант. Минута переполнена");
         }
         // Гарантия учтенных инвариантов !
         $this->seconds++;
        // Нет необходимости проверять после этого метода инварианты
    }
    
    public function show(){
        // Гарантия учтенных инвариантов !
       
         echo $this->seconds;
       // Нет необходимости проверять до и после этого метода инварианты
    }

}
  
try{
    $minute = new Minute(58);
    $minute->addSecond();
    $minute->addSecond();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]