# Что такое инвариант цикла?

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю книгу про алгоритмы и структуры данных, и не совсем понимаю, что такое инвариант цикла.

Это гарантия того, что на каждой итерации цикла происходит одно и тоже?

Comment: разве в книге по алгоритмам и структурам данных не объясняется что это такое?

Comment: Да что-то не совсем понимаю, что имеется ввиду https://prnt.sc/11pm7r9

Comment: Это выражение истинное на каждой итерации цикла. Для примера из книги: на каждой итерации цикла, есть такой подмассив, в котором все элементы отсортированы

Comment: не совсем дубликат, но все же [Что такое инвариант в ООП?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/858650/179763)

Comment: @Grundy Но на каждой итерации цикла, по идее, есть еще и неотсортированный массив. Это тоже инвариант или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 7):

Инвариант цикла описывает состояние данных на каждом шаге. Не всё состояние - а только то, что важно с точки зрения реализуемого алгоритма.

В доказательной алгоритмистике требуется убедиться, что состояние изменяется определённым образом, приближая нас к нужному результату.

Для пошаговой сортировки (пузырьком, вставками, выбором) существенно то, что после каждого (k-го) оборота внешнего цикла мы имеем отсортированную часть из k элементов (в том числе и до выполнения алгоритма - начальное состояние, "инициализация").

Таким образом, после каждого оборота длина отсортированной части растёт, и в конце концов отсортирован весь массив.

В данном случае состояние оставшейся части массива нас не волнует.